# Why is the PartitionKey field of an Azure Event Hub EventData null?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-webjobs, azure-eventhub

I'm consuming `EventData` events from an Azure Event Hub using Azure Functions 1.x. However, I noticed that the `PartitionKey` is always null. Yet, `Offset` and `SequenceNumber` are both populated.

I know it's optional for the sender to set the `PartitionKey`. In fact, it's [recommended](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-programming-guide#availability-considerations) not to set it for performance reasons. However, I assumed that somewhere along the way to the consumer, the `PartitionKey` would be set with the partition that processed the `EventData`.

If that's not the case, what's the point of sending the `Offset` and `SequenceNumber`? Each partition maintains its own `Offset` and `SequenceNumber`. If I wanted to replay an event, how would I do so without knowing the `PartitionKey`?

Edit:

I just found out that if I bind to the `PartitionContext`, I can view the `PartitionId` that the `EventData` came from. Why isn't this used to populate the `PartitionKey` on the `EventData`? Is this a bug with Azure Functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `PartitionKey` is [different](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6fa9e76b-d317-4ebe-821e-c00f856553f7/leasepartitionid-vs-eventdatapartitionid-in-azure-event-hub-implementation-using?forum=servbus#998631f0-437f-4b16-8495-560e4f68fb61) from the `PartitionId`:

> PartitionId is different than PartitionKey. Partition keys are used to
>   ensure same partition keys to land on the same partition ids. You can
>   think PartitionKey to partitionId relation as "f(partitionKey) =
>   partitionId" where f is a hashing function.

The `PartitionKey` will be null if the sender didn't set it, as mentioned by [Ling Toh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49454349/why-is-the-partitionkey-field-of-an-azure-event-hub-eventdata-null#comment-86044264).

You can access the `PartitionId` in Azure Functions by using the `PartitionContext` binding.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to obtain the partitionKey property from the EventData object. Kindly see, https://medium.com/@jeffhollan/in-order-event-processing-with-azure-functions-bb661eb55428

Comment: I was/am using `EventData`, but as I said, `PartitionKey` is `null`.

Comment: If you do not set the partition key when the message is sent, then the EventData object will not have the PartitionKey property set. This behavior repros even in a console app using EventProcessorHost (the receiver used by Azure Functions). Perhaps you could open an issue with the ServiceBus team regarding this behavior at https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/issues